# "Every time I eat (I'm eating) crabs, I feel (I'm feeling) sick" - what difference the continuous aspect makes

Tags: grammar, continuous

If I say "Every time I **eat** crabs, I **feel** sick" (it is a usual fact that will last  all my life.)

But is it possible to say "Every time **I'm  eating** crabs, **I feel** sick." Does it change the meaning of the first part of the sentence? when I say that I am not necessarily eating crabs right now.

Would it be possible to say "Every time **I'm  eating** crabs, **I'm feeling**  sick", what would that mean... a temporary situation ( won't last  all my life.)

Comment: The merged-word spelling "everytime" is frowned upon, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everytime).

Comment: We say "eating crab". Like "eating shrimp"; crab and shrimp are mass nouns. (AmE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Whenever I eat crab, I feel sick afterwards.**

Or

**Whenever I've eaten crab, I feel sick.**

The last tense I'd choose would be the progressive, unless I wished to imply that the sick feeling comes over me while I'm having the meal.

**Whenever I'm eating crab, I begin to feel sick.**

An important thing to bear in mind here is the sequence and nature of the actions. As we can see from the last example, the sick feeling can be an *incipient* feeling (begin to feel). In the first example, using the present tense, we have *habitual* action; to make abundantly clear that the sick feeling is the result of eating crab (and not the reason for eating crab), we use *afterwards*.

**Whenever I eat chicken soup, I'm feeling sick.**

In the case of the chicken soup, it is eaten *because* you feel sick. The implication is that you don't normally eat chicken soup, and treat it as a remedy.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible, but we don't.

There is no meaning added by using the present continuous in this example. In fact, using "every time" makes it clear that you are *not* talking about *now*, so the present continuous is inappropriate.

Comment: In my opinion, the present continuous gives more of a sense that the observed correlation is a recent development.

Answer (score 0):

The repeated use of the progressive form is usually used to indicate immediacy, usually as part of an informal sort of storytelling.

> "I'm visiting my in-laws, see? And every night they feed me these
>   really good crabs. And every time I'm eating crabs, I'm feeling sick.
>   And then it hits me - they're trying to poison me!"

Contrast this with a more standard use of tenses.

> I went to visit my in-laws, and every evening we had excellent crab
>   dishes. I soon noticed that every time I ate these great crabs I felt
>   sick, and I realized that my in-laws were trying to poison me.